# Mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that I need to query an array subdocuments. The data looks like this:

```
{
    "name" : "test",
    "code" : 417,
    "rates": {},
    "coverage": [
      {
        "limit": 125,
        "factors": {}
      },
      {
        "limit": 130,
        "factors": {}
      },
      {
        "limit": 135,
        "factors": {}
      }
    ]
}
```

If the input is 127 I need to select the highest coverage that is not more than the limit. I'm doing that like this:

```
db.getCollection('rates').aggregate([
    {$match : {"name" : "test", "code": 417}},
    {$unwind : "$coverage"},
    {$match : { "coverage.limit": { $lte: 327 }}},
    {$sort : { "coverage.limit": -1 }},
    {$limit : 1 },
    {$project : { "factors": "$coverage.factors" }}
])
```

But now I also need to get the coverage one limit above. I'd like to do it in the same query but I'm not sure how. Or would it be better to get the whole doc and use code to do this?

Comment: may be I'm missing something here you can replace your project with `{$project : { "factors": "$coverageA.factors" }}` with `{$project : { "coverage": "$coverageA" }}`

Comment: The coverageA was supposed to be just coverage. Changed it. Still doesn't give me the next coverage up.

Comment: you want the last two coverages? or you want one coverage before limit and one after ? it will help if you can add the expected response in the question

Comment: Yep. The problem is I need to find the highest limit that is not over the input but once I get that I don't know how to get the one above it without another query.